# Sql Query to check availability by day and max people

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Hello this is are 2 tables on my db :
[image]

I'm trying to get the hotels available for a interval of dates.
In the Rooms table are defined the types of rooms : eg Signe:max_guests=1, Triple : max_guests=3
So for 10 people booking i need something like:

```
SELECT  SUM(rooms.max_guests * av.RoomAvailable) AS maxPeople 
FROM av AS av INNER JOIN rooms 
ON av.room = rooms.ID AND av.DateofDays BETWEEN '09/28/2012' AND '10/03/2012' 
GROUP BY av.userid
HAVING Count(*) >= 6
```

but this doesn't really fit my requirements ..it return me total max_people available/ userID  i just need to check if every day for each userID(hotel) there's >= 10 (max_people) available

Thank yo for your help

Update: if i use this query :

```
SELECT  av.userid, av.DateofDays, SUM(rooms.max_guests * 

av.RoomAvailable) AS maxPeople 
FROM av AS av INNER JOIN rooms 
ON av.room = rooms.ID AND av.DateofDays BETWEEN '09/28/2012' 

AND '10/03/2012' 
GROUP BY av.userid, av.DateofDays
ORDER BY av.userid, av.DateofDays
```

i get this:
[image]

Comment: here are you trying to find all the rooms available between set of days  for sepecif number of people?

Comment: yes exactly if for each day has availability. it just need to return me only the userid that has availability for a max_people betwen a days interval

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to manually put in the number of days in the count.

```
WITH cte AS (
SELECT  av.userid, av.DateofDays, SUM(rooms.max_guests * av.RoomAvailable) AS maxPeople 
FROM av AS av INNER JOIN rooms 
ON av.room = rooms.ID AND av.DateofDays BETWEEN '09/28/2012' AND '10/03/2012' 
GROUP BY av.userid, av.DateofDays
HAVING SUM(rooms.max_guests * av.RoomAvailable) >= 10 
)
select cte.userid 
from cte 
group by av.userid 
having COUNT(*) = 6
```

Comment: thank you but because of HAVING Count(*) >= 10  i don't see any result and without it i see results that match criteria and have more than 10 max_guests .. let me try attaching a new photo

Comment: thanks but i need just to return me the userid that has availability for each day. In this case if i delete the availability for 09/29/2012 still show me that list except no record for 09/29/2012

Comment: thank you Blam , any idea why i get Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The multi-part identifier "av.userid" could not be bound. ?

Comment: saw it should be group by cte.userid thank you is working great

Answer (score 0):

Just add dateofdays to your SELECT and GROUP BY. This will return just the days/hotels >=10

Comment: thank you .. i thought so either but it returns me no result .. if i take off the HAVING Count(*) >= 6 then it will show me 6 records for each userid for the 6 different dates with max_people but actually i need to show me the userId that has for each date max_days >= 10

Comment: please look at the updated photo this is what i get. i need to show me only userid 1 because that has more than 10 max_people in all day interval